# How can I directly log in into phpBB3 from my website?

Tags: php, phpbb3

I integrated phpbb3 into my site.When a user login into my website then there is a tab called forum. If he clicks on the forum it will take to a page where it asking user name and password to login. But i want when the user clicks on the forum then he has to directly go to forum with his account details without logging again.

Please help me......

Comment: Are you using any CMS at all? Usually, this sort of thing requires synchronized user tables between phpBB and your main site's setup.  I've heard of plugins for Joomla, for instance, that handle this for you.  If we know more about your setup we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can also use jquery/ajax to login without the user leaving the page, when a success is returned from the ajax call then refresh the current page. I use the same thing for my facebook for phpbb mod I develop

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this exact same thing, A user registers on my site and at the same time i would automaticaly create them a phpbb account as well.

Here is the code I use to register them (I don't use the phphash function for passwords, I use my hash functions. The md5 hash for the password is actually hashing a already hashed password):

```
//Register the user on the forum code

global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $user, $db, $config, $cache, $template,$auth;             

 define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './Forums/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
require('./Forums/includes/functions_user.php');

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('viewtopic');

$user_row = array(
     'username'                => $username,                //REQUIRED IN FORM
     'user_password'           => md5($password_1),            //REQUIRED IN FORM
     'user_email'              => $email,            //REQUIRED IN FORM
     'group_id'                => 2,//(int) $group_id,
     'user_timezone'           => $timezone = date(Z) / 3600,//(float) $data[tz],
     'user_dst'                => date(I),//$is_dst,
     'user_lang'               => $user->lang_name,//$data[lang],
     'user_type'               => USER_NORMAL,//$user_type,
     'user_actkey'             => '',//$user_actkey,
     'user_ip'                 => $user->ip,
     'user_regdate'            => time(),
     'user_inactive_reason'    => 0,//$user_inactive_reason,
     'user_inactive_time'      => 0,//$user_inactive_time,
);


 //Register user on the forum
 $forum_user_id = user_add($user_row);

 return "both_registered";
```

Then to log them in I use this:

```
//Now log them into the forum
global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $user, $db, $config, $cache, $template, $auth;             

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : getcwd().'/Forums/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
require(getcwd().'/Forums/includes/functions_user.php');

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

// Begin phpBB login
if(!$user->data['is_registered'])
{
  $username = $username;
  $password = $password;
  $autologin = 1;

  $result = $auth->login($username, $password, $autologin);
  //print_r($result);
}
```

Obviously you might need to change this around a little, I do alot of checks before it even gets to registering them or logging them in. Hopefully this helps and if anyone sees something i am not doing right then please let me know.